# Is my <link rel="alternate"> interfering with my <link rel="amphtml">?

Tags: amp-html, rel

I've build an AMP version of (a section of) a website. The AMP pages themselves are tested and valid, and they have canonical links to the desktop site. That's all fine.

On the desktop site, I've specified the `<link rel="amphtml"...>` to point at the corresponding AMP page. All should be working, but in Google Search Console, I'm seeing an error: "Referenced AMP URL is not an AMP"

Now, the linked AMP pages are **definitely** valid AMP, so I'm getting cranky.

The only thing I can conceive being a problem is the desktop site also has a `<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="[mobile version of site]">`... perhaps Googlebot is confusing the *alternate* page with the *AMP* page?

To be transparent, I don't have much access to the desktop site - I can't actually remove the `<link rel="alternate">` code.

Thoughts? Insight?

---

### Further Info:

In Google Search Console, the linked AMP pages is being reported as "not an AMP":

[Search console report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ1j4.png)

However, if you run the URL through the AMP validator, it passes as expected:

[Validate AMP](https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fww8.ikea.com%2Fca%2Fen%2Famp%2Fideas%2Fcreate-a-dream-kid-s-room.html)

Comment: Got a link to the page?

Comment: https://www.ikea.com/ca/en/ideas/201924_idip21a/

Comment: Could you show HTML snippets of all <link rel=...> in your "desktop" page? Or the link to your desktop page that contains <link rel="amphtml" ...>.

Comment: Desktop site head links:  ```<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m2.ikea.com/ca/en/ideas/top-tips-organize-laundry-pub0330c3d1">```                   ```<link rel="amphtml" href="https://ww8.ikea.com/ca/en/amp/ideas/top-tips-organize-laundry.html">```

Comment: I don't see the `<link rel="amphtml" ...>` on your canonical URL - has it been removed?

Comment: It actually gets added via javascript... if you _view source_ you won't see it, but if you _inspect_ the page you will. I've tested via Google Search Console to ensure Googlebot will see the rendered tag.